# how to use declare-fun with values in Z3 SMTLIB

Tags: z3

while prowling stackoverflow and the internet for bits of info about Z3 i came across an example which looks like a planning problem.
They `(declare-fun myFunc (Int Int) Int)` and later use expression of the form 

`(assert (= (myFunc 3 3) 9) )
(assert (= (myFunc 4 4) 16 )`

to fill it with values. I havent seen this kind of expression in other examples, i read it like "it is true that the function myFunc with parameters 3 3 evalutaes to 9".
I converted one of my functions which does a simple calculation to this form of 'lookup-function'. Great performance boost !!
Applying this to another function which should return a Bool turned out to be not so easy. The model shows me that it has this internal form:

```
; define neighbor-property by position distance, instead of row/col-distance
(declare-fun isPosNeighbor ( Int Int Int ) Bool )    ; this is later filled with values

(assert (= (isPosNeighbor 0 0 0 ) false  ) ) ; provide the default value
(assert (= (isPosNeighbor   1   0  1 ) true ) ) 
(assert (= (isPosNeighbor   1   1  2 ) true ) ) 
(assert (= (isPosNeighbor   1   3  4 ) true ) ) 
(assert (= (isPosNeighbor   1   5  6 ) true ) ) 

(assert (= (isPosNeighbor  10   0 10 ) true ) ) 
(assert (= (isPosNeighbor  10   1 11 ) true ) ) 
(assert (= (isPosNeighbor  10   2 12 ) true ) ) 
(assert (= (isPosNeighbor  10   3 13 ) true ) ) 
(assert (= (isPosNeighbor  10  12 22 ) true ) ) 

(check-sat)
(get-model)
(eval  (isPosNeighbor 33 4 1))   ; should return false
```

How can i force isPosNeighbor to return false for values not given? How can i influence the final true in the ite-sequence ?

```
sat 
(model (define-fun isPosNeighbor ((x!0 Int) (x!1 Int) (x!2 Int)) Bool
  (ite (and (= x!0 0) (= x!1 0) (= x!2 0)) false 
  (ite (and (= x!0 1) (= x!1 0) (= x!2 1)) true
  (ite (and (= x!0 1) (= x!1 1) (= x!2 2)) true 
  (ite (and (= x!0 1) (= x!1 7) (= x!2 8)) true 
  (ite (and (= x!0 1) (= x!1 8) (= x!2 9)) true 
  (ite (and (= x!0 10) (= x!1 0) (= x!2 10)) true 
  (ite (and (= x!0 10) (= x!1 1) (= x!2 11)) true 
  (ite (and (= x!0 10) (= x!1 2) (= x!2 12)) true 
  (ite (and (= x!0 10) (= x!1 3) (= x!2 13)) true
  (ite (and (= x!0 10) (= x!1 12) (= x!2 22)) true 
    true                ;; <<<< how to set this default-value ??
   ))))))))))) ) 

   true
```

Comment: the planning problem is in this post on stackoverflow:

Does Z3 take a longer time to give an unsat result compared to a sat result?

Answer (score 1):

One can adjust the default value by rewriting the input formula as follows:

```
(set-option :produce-models true)

(define-fun isPosNeighbor ((x!0 Int) (x!1 Int) (x!2 Int)) Bool
    (ite (or
            (and (= x!0  1) (= x!1  0) (= x!2  1))
            (and (= x!0  1) (= x!1  1) (= x!2  2))
            (and (= x!0  1) (= x!1  7) (= x!2  8))
            (and (= x!0  1) (= x!1  8) (= x!2  9))
            (and (= x!0 10) (= x!1  0) (= x!2 10))
            (and (= x!0 10) (= x!1  1) (= x!2 11)) 
            (and (= x!0 10) (= x!1  2) (= x!2 12)) 
            (and (= x!0 10) (= x!1  3) (= x!2 13))
            (and (= x!0 10) (= x!1 12) (= x!2 22)) 
        ) true false
))

(check-sat)
(get-model)

(eval  (isPosNeighbor 33 4 1))
(eval  (isPosNeighbor 0 0 0)) 
(eval  (isPosNeighbor 1 0 1))
```

Note that there is no need to provide a special case for `0 0 0`.

Moreover, if the value of the function is not know *a priori*, `true` and `false` can be replaced with arbitrary Boolean expressions.

The output matches the desired behaviour:

```
~$ z3 t.smt2 
sat
(model 
)
false
false
true
```

Comment: sure, thats a way to get the values. Stll it does not explain how to influence the last value. I did some experiments and seems that it uses a majority vote on the given example-values. When i change my example so that 6 input-triples return false, the last value also changes to false. i could not find anything specific in the examples in rise4fun or the SMTLIB-reference..

Comment: There's no such thing as "last" value. SMT solvers find a model that satisfy your constraints, and they're free to pick values so long as all constraints are satisfied. As Patrick mentioned, you have to explicitly tell it what value to use if you want a "default" result; either via quantification or somehow forcing all other values to take the default value (as Patrick did). Note that SMT solvers are not like Prolog with a closed world assumption: All assignments are valid so long as constraints are not violated.